# RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data

Tags: regex, base64, standards-compliance, rfc

Is it possible to use a RegEx to validate, or sanitize Base64 data?  That's the simple question, but the factors that drive this question are what make it difficult.

I have a Base64 decoder that can not fully rely on the input data to follow the RFC specs.  So, the issues I face are issues like perhaps Base64 data that may not be broken up into 78 (I think it's 78, I'd have to double check the RFC, so don't ding me if the exact number is wrong) character lines, or that the lines may not end in `CRLF`; in that it may have only a `CR`, or `LF`, or maybe neither.

So, I've had a hell of a time parsing Base64 data formatted as such.  Due to this, examples like the following become impossible to decode reliably.  I will only display partial MIME headers for brevity.

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBzaW1wbGUgQVNDSUkgQmFzZTY0IGZvciBTdGFja092ZXJmbG93IGV4YW1wbGUu
```

OK, so parsing that is no problem, and is exactly the result we would expect.    And in 99% of the cases, using any code to at least verify that each char in the buffer is a valid base64 char works perfectly.  But the next example throws a wrench into the mix.

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

http://www.stackoverflow.com
VGhpcyBpcyBzaW1wbGUgQVNDSUkgQmFzZTY0IGZvciBTdGFja092ZXJmbG93IGV4YW1wbGUu
```

This is a version of Base64 encoding that I have seen in some viruses and other things that attempt to take advantage of some mail readers' desire to parse MIME at all costs, versus ones that go strictly by the book, or rather RFC; if you will.

My Base64 decoder decodes the second example to the following data stream.  And keep in mind here, the original stream is all ASCII data!

```
[0x]86DB69FFFC30C2CB5A724A2F7AB7E5A307289951A1A5CC81A5CC81CDA5B5C1B19481054D0D
2524810985CD94D8D08199BDC8814DD1858DAD3DD995C999B1BDDC8195E1B585C1B194B8
```

Does anyone have a good way to solve both problems at once?  I'm not sure it's even possible, outside of doing two transforms on the data with different rules applied, and comparing the results.  However, if you took that approach, which output do you trust?  It seems that ASCII heuristics is about the *best* solution, but how much more code, execution time, and complexity would that add to something as complicated as a virus scanner, which this code is actually involved in?  How would you train the heuristics engine to learn what is acceptable Base64, and what isn't?

---

### **UPDATE:**

Due to the number of views this question continues to recieve, I've decided to post the simple regex that I've been using in a C# application for 3 years now, with hundreds of thousands of transactions.  Honestly, I like the answer given by [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo/) the best, which is why I picked it as the selected answer.  But to anyone using C#, and looking for a very quick way to at least detect whether a string, or `byte[]` contains valid Base64 data or not, the following regex patterns work very well for me.

```
^[-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$
```

Or a more simplified pattern as suggested by [kael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065427/kael):

```
^[-A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,3}$
```

And yes, this is just for a *STRING* of Base64 data, NOT a properly formatted [RFC1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341) message.  So, if you are dealing with data of this type, please take that into account before attempting to use the above regex.  If you are dealing with Base16, Base32, Radix or even Base64 for other purposes (URLs, file names, XML Encoding, etc.), then it is *highly* recommended that you read [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) that [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo/) mentioned in their answer as you need to be well aware of the charset and terminators used by the implementation before attempting to use the suggestions in this question/answer set.

Comment: I guess that you have to define the task better. It is completely unclear what is your aim: be strict? parse 100% of the samples? ...

Comment: You first example should be 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNpbXBsZSBBU0NJSSBCYXNlNjQgZXhhbXBsZSBmb3IgU3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdy4='

Comment: Why don't use a standard solution in your language? Why do you need hand-written parser based on regexs?

Comment: @JF - Well, I don't.  I have looked at other methods, and didn't have a lot o luck, so I thought I'd give RegEx a try.  This is all C/C++, if it matters.  And I already do the Pre-parsing of ANYTHING non-b64, toss it, and decode the rest.

Comment: @ADEpt - The aim is to be able to parse 100% of the time regardless of how badly formatted, or damaged the source is.  (I've event delt with viruses that put random BINARY data inside the b64 data)...

Comment: How can I replace non Base64 chars with empty strings?

Comment: @Sapphire - That depends.  What you are asking is worthy of a whole new question.  There are three ways you can do it, that I see.  1) Eat the bad chars as you are decoding.  2) Use a RegEx replace, to replace any non Base64 char with "", or 3) Use a function in code to walk your buffer, and test each char against a Base64 table, and if the char isn't there, simply replace the instance with char(32), or " "...  Contact me off SO, and I'd be happy to share some C code to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note: According to RFC 2045 the new line is added after 76 characters: "The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more than 76 characters each. All line breaks or other characters not found in Base64 alphabet must be ignored by decoding software".

Comment: Great question. Though I tried the **UPDATE** regex by running it against a base64-encoded SHA returned by NPM and [it failed](https://regexr.com/3uc7a) whereas the regex in selected answer [works just fine](https://regexr.com/3uc7a).

Comment: Not sure how the **UPDATE** regex is still posted without correction, but it looks like the author _meant_ to put the `^` outside the brackets, as a start-anchor. However, a much better regex, without getting as complicated as the accepted answer, would be `^[-A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,3}$`

Comment: @kael good catch. I have updated this, looks like it wasn't before because the minimum chars needed for an update on SO is 6, but that's only a 2 char update. I added some backticks to the line endings to meet the minimum

Comment: Thanks @IanPringle.  I just updated the whole answer to include both expressions to allow the readers to compare and contrast the two.  I suppose I could have just removed my dusty old pattern replacing it with kael's pattern.  I thought it might be of some value to the readers to show both patterns. and give kael credit for his pattern.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

From the [RFC 4648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt):

> Base encoding of data is used in many situations to store or transfer data in environments that, perhaps for legacy reasons, are restricted to US-ASCII data.

So it depends on the purpose of usage of the encoded data if the data should be considered as dangerous.

But if you’re just looking for a regular expression to match Base64 encoded words, you can use the following:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

Comment: That doesn't deal with the 'white space' at line ends.  I'm not sure whether program always put the newline at a 4-byte boundary - it would be reasonable, but then following the standard would be reasonable too, but people don't do it.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to strip out all whitespace (which is ignored as per the RFC) before validation.

Comment: What about words that do *not* end with paddings, eg encoded data where the length is a multiple of 4?

Comment: The last non-capturing group for the padding is optional.

Comment: At first I was skeptical of the complexity, but it validates quite well. If you'd just like to match base64-ish I'd come up with doing ^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]={0,3}$, this is better!

Comment: This regexp doesn't work on word *name*, it thinks that it is Base64 encoded

Comment: @BogdanNechyporenko That's because `name` is a valid Base64 encoding of the (hex) byte sequence `9d a9 9e`.

Comment: @Lodewijk's comment sparked an idea of sanity. If we fix his broken regex (incorrect padding-length and missing quantifier `+` after first character-class) to `^[+/0-9A-Za-z]+={0,2}$` and perform a simple multiple-of-4 check (`strBase64.length%4===0` or bitwise mask: `strBase64.length&3===0`) *before* this regex, we discard 75% of invalid string-lengths (not a multiple of 4) by a simple computation instead of 'abusing' regex to also perform a simple calculation. The regex then catches the edge-case of the empty string (and UTF-16 surrogate pairs) that slipped through the multiple-of-4 check.

Comment: Don't remember about '-' and '_' characters

Comment: Can I ask a question that's driving me nuts? How is "Paul" valid base64?

Comment: This expression matches any string which has length multiples of 4

Comment: ^([A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{3}(=){0,1}|[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{2}(==){0,1})?$, little bit modification, "=", "==" is optional while providing.

Comment: `^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})$` must escape backlash

Comment: In regular expressions, the forward slash `/` character does not need to be escaped unless it's used as the `delimiter for the regex pattern itself`. In JavaScript, regular expressions are often delimited by forward slashes, like `/pattern/`. In such cases, if you want to `match a forward slash within the pattern`, you need to escape it as `\/`.

Comment: However, in regex pattern `^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})$` the forward slashes within the character classes `[ ]` are not functioning as delimiters. They are just characters to be matched. Therefore, escaping them with a backslash is unnecessary, and strict lint will result in `Unnecessary escape character: \/ no-useless-escape`.

Comment: Lastly, the forward slash `/` character does not need to be escaped unless it's used as the `delimiter for the regex pattern itself` applies to ECMAScript(JavaScript), Python, Golang, Java 8+, C# & Rust Regex flavours, however an unescaped delimiter must be escaped in PHP as it is not valid patter there and will result in an error.

Answer (score 48):

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

This one is good, but will match an empty String

This one does not match empty string :

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$
```

Comment: Why is an empty string invalid?

Comment: it is not. but if you are using a regex to find out if a given string is or is not base64, chances are you are not interested in empty strings. At least i know i am not.

Comment: Just replace the star/asterisk operator `*` with `+` like so: `^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})+(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$` to prevent empty strings from matching the pattern.

Comment: @LayZee : if you do so, you force the base64 string to contain at least a 4-size block, rendering valid values such as `MQ==` not a match to your expression

Comment: It doesn't match `AQENVg688MSGlEgdOJpjIUC`

Comment: @ruslan nor should it. this is not a valid base 64 string. (size is 23, which is not // 4). `AQENVg688MSGlEgdOJpjIUC=` is the valid form.

Comment: @njzk2 How about replacing the last `?` with `{1}`?

Comment: @JinKwon base64 ends with 0, 1 or 2 `=`. The last `?` allows for 0 `=`. Replacing it with `{1}` requires 1 or 2 ending `=`

Answer (score 11):

The answers presented so far fail to check that the Base64 string has all pad bits set to 0, as required for it to be the canonical representation of Base64 (which is important in some environments, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.5) and therefore, they allow *aliases* that are different encodings for the same binary string. This could be a security problem in some applications.

Here is the regexp that verifies that the given string is not just valid base64, but also the canonical base64 string for the binary data:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=)?$
```

The cited RFC considers the empty string as valid (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-10) therefore the above regex also does.

The equivalent regular expression for base64url (again, refer to the above RFC) is:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9_-]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9_-][AQgw]==|[A-Za-z0-9_-]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=)?$
```

Comment: for base64url, `[\w-]` could tighten that up a bit

Answer (score 6):

To validate **base64 image** we can use this regex

> /^data:image/(?:gif|png|jpeg|bmp|webp)(?:;charset=utf-8)?;base64,(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[+/])+={0,2}

```
  private validBase64Image(base64Image: string): boolean {
    const regex = /^data:image\/(?:gif|png|jpeg|bmp|webp|svg\+xml)(?:;charset=utf-8)?;base64,(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[+/])+={0,2}/;
    return base64Image && regex.test(base64Image);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful regarding the meta properties at the beginning of a base64 image string. One suggestion: There is (at least) one mime type missing, `svg+xml`, so the first capturing group should probably be extended to `(?:gif|png|jpeg|bmp|webp|svg\+xml)`.

Comment: @HynekS. Yes. I updated my answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: `(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[+/])` can be simplified to `[A-Za-z0-9+/]`

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative regular expression:

```
^(?=(.{4})*$)[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}$
```

It satisfies the following conditions:

- The string length must be a multiple of four - `(?=^(.{4})*$)`
- The content must be alphanumeric characters or + or / - `[A-Za-z0-9+/]*`
- It can have up to two padding (=) characters on the end - `={0,2}`
- It accepts empty strings

Answer (score 5):

Neither a "**:**" nor a "**.**" will show up in valid Base64, so I think you can unambiguously throw away the `http://www.stackoverflow.com` line. In Perl, say, something like

```
my $sanitized_str = join q{}, grep {!/[^A-Za-z0-9+\/=]/} split /\n/, $str;

say decode_base64($sanitized_str);
```

might be what you want. It produces

*This is simple ASCII Base64 for StackOverflow exmaple.*

Comment: I can agree there, but all the OTHER letters in the URL do happen to be valid base64...  So, where do you draw the line?  Just at line breaks?  (I have seen ones where there is just a couple random chars in the middle of the line.  Can't toss the rest of the line just because of that, IMHO)...

Comment: @LarryF: unless there's integrity checking on the base-64 encoded data, you can't tell what to do with any base-64 block of data containing incorrect characters. Which is the best heuristic: ignore the incorrect characters (allowing any and all correct ones) or reject the lines, or reject the lot?

Comment: (continued): the short answer is "it depends" - on where the data comes from and the sorts of mess you find in it.

Comment: (resumed): I see from comments to the question that you want to accept anything that might be base-64.  So simply map each and every character that's not in your base-64 alphabet (note that there are URL-safe and other such variant encodings) including the newlines and colons, and take what's left.

Answer (score 5):

The best regexp which I could find up till now is in here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-regex

which is in the current version looks like:

```
module.exports = function (opts) {
  opts = opts || {};
  var regex = '(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}\\n?)*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)';

  return opts.exact ? new RegExp('(?:^' + regex + '$)') :
                    new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + regex, 'g');
};
```

Comment: Maybe better without `\\n?`.

Comment: This will fail on JSON strings

Answer (score 5):

The shortest regex to check RFC-4648 compiliance enforcing canonical encoding (i.e. all pad bits set to 0):

```
^(?=(.{4})*$)[A-Za-z0-9+/]*([AQgw]==|[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=)?$
```

Actually this is the mix of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63758783/9868257) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64467300/9868257) answers.

Answer (score 1):

I [found](https://regexmatch.dev/regex/validate-base64-single-line-string-621dcb860f5d0e67d245a6d3) a solution that works very well

```
^(?:([a-z0-9A-Z+\/]){4})*(?1)(?:(?1)==|(?1){2}=|(?1){3})$
```

It will match the following strings

```
VGhpcyBpcyBzaW1wbGUgQVNDSUkgQmFzZTY0IGZvciBTdGFja092ZXJmbG93IGV4YW1wbGUu
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcw==
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3U=
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3Vy
```

while it won't match any of those invalid

```
YW5@IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcw==
YW55IGNhc=5hbCBwbGVhcw==
YW55%%%%IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3V
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc
YW***55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVh=
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc==
YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc===
```

Answer (score 1):

My simplified version of Base64 regex:

`^[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}$`

Simplification is that it doesn't check that its length is a multiple of 4. If you need that - use other answers. Mine is focusing on simplicity.

To test it: https://regex101.com/r/zdtGSH/1