# How to pass parameters to an awk command from a running Node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, awk, child-process

The following Javascript code doesn't pass a command string correctly:

```
cp = require("child_process");
var command = "awk < " + mypath + "\" \$3 ~ \"^rs\" {print \$3}\""
cp.exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {});
```

Is there a more appropriate Node package or Javascript workaround for passing quotation marks and dollar signs to an Awk interpreter that gets invoked in a Bash environment when using child_process in Node?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but this looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22827128/942223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [native-Node awk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awk), consider using this instead.

Comment: this awk package is bullshit, code is obfuscated and does not actually work, check the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if I am reading this correctly:

"awk < " + mypath + "\" \$3 ~ \"^rs\" {print \$3}\""

it suggests that your parameter order may need tweaking, i.e. start with simple awk:

```
awk '{print $0}' /some_file # print each line
```

Taking the above (not clear) but do you mean something like:

```
awk '/^rs/ {print $3}' /some_file ##
```

# for each line starting with 'rs' print 3rd variable?

Perhaps something like:

Ok, modified a bit; since I'm not familiar with the solution that you are 'calling from', then you will need to tweak appropriately.

```
"awk '/^rs/{print \$3}'" + "mypath"  ## ?
```

Or, perhaps (not sure if you need to escape $3):

```
"awk '/^rs/{print $3}'" + "mypath"  ## ?
```

Comment: Yes, the `mypath` variable includes the filename and I want to print the third column of each line starting with rs, but unfortunately the first backslash in your solution is indicated as the reason for throwing `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: Note, suggesting 'something like' - so above should be close enough to get you to a solution with some tinkering on your part - check the docs for your programming environment - it should specify what/how to 'format arguments'.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Child-process node package.
exec function.

//
npm install child-process
exec(`awk command`, (error, stdout, stderr)=>{}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).