# Escape bash variable in node over ssh

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh

When executing a bash command in node and passing a dynamic parameter, the standard way to go is to use spawn and avoid escaping. That is:

```
const filename = 'file with spaces'
spawn('ls', [filename]) // All good, received 'file with spaces'
```

This is foolproof since filename is passed as a standalone variable to bash.

Now, what happens if I want to do the same through ssh? The following is **not** an option:

```
const filename = 'file with spaces'
spawn('ssh', [host, 'ls', filename]) // Wrong!! Received 'file' 'with' 'spaces'
```

Ssh is accepting ls and filename as vargars. Joining it and executing, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I think you might need to escape single quotes like `filename = '\'file with spaces\''`

Comment: No, that is not good. That will depend a lot on the input, which is dynamic

Comment: Passing a single string (suitably constructed) is your only real option; `ssh` is just taking its arguments and naively joining them into a single string to use with `$SHELL -c` on the remote host anyway.

Comment: Make a function `quote_me(string)` that puts single quotes around the input and try `spawn('ssh', [host, 'ls', quote_me(filename)])`.

Comment: @WalterA escaping characters is super tricky, and there can always be cases where it doesn't work. For example in your case the filename could have quotes in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pass the value using base64 which has expected characters and then escape in bash

```
spawn('ssh', [host, 'ls', `"$(echo ${btoa(filename)} | base64 -d)"`])
```

Comment: `btoa` doesn't work without a custom function or module in Node, but you can use `Buffer.from(filename).toString("base64")` to accomplish the task.