# Is string base 64 encoded?

Tags: php, base64

How can I find whether a string is a data encoded with `base64_encode()` function or not?

Is it possible?

Comment: It would be a lot better if you would not need such a detection at all. Many experienced programmers can live without it and I am sure you could.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074

Comment: @Gumbo: I did not add the [php5] tag - my edit took longer to submit than yours did somehow. I've removed it now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Attempt to decode it strictly against the Base64 alphabet. The second parameter allows you to enforce this strict check; by leaving it out, the decoding function simply strips out illegal characters before decoding:

```
if (base64_decode($str, true) === false)
{
    echo 'Not a Base64-encoded string';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(base64_encode(base64_decode($img, true)) === $img)
   echo 'is a Base64-encoded string' ;
```