# Regular expression to extract the value of hidden element

Tags: regex

I have html pages with `hidden` element as below:

```
< input type=hidden id="xl_aux2" name="xl_aux2" value="???" >
```

Value contains `base64 string`. So what will be the `regular expression` that I can use to extract the value from above `hidden` element?

Comment: And what language you are using? Why not use DOM to read form field's value?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
value="([^"]*)"
```

The data you want is in the first group.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer with regular expression for Base64 encoded string :

[RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

So the result expression will be like this :

```
/.*value=\"(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?\".*/
```