# How to check for a valid Base64 encoded string

Tags: c#, validation, base64

Is there a way in C# to see if a string is Base 64 encoded other than just trying to convert it and see if there is an error?  I have code code like this:

```
// Convert base64-encoded hash value into a byte array.
byte[] HashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Value);
```

I want to avoid the "Invalid character in a Base-64 string" exception that happens if the value is not valid base 64 string. I want to just check and return false instead of handling an exception because I expect that sometimes this value is not going to be a base 64 string.  Is there some way to check before using the Convert.FromBase64String function?

Comment: It depends on how "thorough" you want the check to be. You can use some pre-validation using a regex as others have answered, but that isn't the only indicator. base64 encoding requires padding in some cases using the `=` sign. If the padding is wrong, it will give an error even though the input matches an expression.

Comment: Title and first sentence ask different question. You can determine if a given string is valid base64 encoded string, but you cannot determine if a string is base64 encoded or not.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Update**: For newer versions of C#, there's a much better alternative, please refer to the answer by Tomas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143400/125981.

---

It's pretty easy to recognize a Base64 string, as it will only be composed of characters `'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '+', '/'` and it is often padded at the end with up to three '=', to make the length a multiple of 4. But instead of comparing these, you'd be better off ignoring the exception, if it occurs.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  I did some testing and it seems it is multiples of 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Its length needs to be a multiple of 3, at the time of encoding, for successful encoding! Sorry about that... and yeah, you're right... The encoded string has a length which is a multiple of 4. Thats why we'd pad upto 3 '=' .

Comment: Marked Correct because you were first to mention the multiple thing.  I updated my question with an implementation of the solution let me know if you see any problems with it.

Comment: This method does not work! I found it after several years. examine it with simple value `test`

Comment: The padding is up to 2 '='. That's because converting only one byte (8bit) will end up in 2 base64 characters and 2 '=' paddings. Try to find an example with 3 '=' at the end if you don't believe me.

Comment: When you only care about validating and don't need to convert, then I think this method will be superior. Using Tomas's answer will inevitably more than double the memory requirement for the process. Context: I'm thinking of an Azure function where I have to take a file in base64 format, and I only need to validate it but not convert it at this point. If I allow, say, a 500mb file to be processed then I have to double max memory requirement if I don't do it this way.

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian if it works or not depends on the chosen underlying encoding *underneath* the Base64 encoding. You cannot say "The letter 'A'" without also specifying in what encoding you expect 'A' to be in. But in your case I guess you ran into this problem: (quote from Wikipedia) `The particular set of 64 characters chosen to represent the 64-digit values for the base varies between implementations. The general strategy is to choose 64 characters that are common to most encodings and that are also printable.` In other words, it doesn't *have* to be the characters given in this answer.

Comment: **Special care is needed for the last 2 characters** of the above answer '+' and '/'.
Different characters are commonly used for these two in different Base64 standards.
Examples: In RFC 3501: (IMAP mailboxes) '/' is replaced with ',' and in RFC 4648 §5: base64url '+' is '-' and '/' is '_' instead. **You need to know your domain to know what the actual encoding characters are!** [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Also note that for the prominent RFC 4648 standard (as well as many other base64 standards) padding with '=' is optional, which means the `length % 4` check is _usually_ not required to be true.

Answer (score 139):

Use [Convert.TryFromBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tryfrombase64string) from C# 7.2 (.NET Core 2.1+ or .NET Standard 2. and higher).

```
public static bool IsBase64String(string base64)
{
   Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[base64.Length]);
   return Convert.TryFromBase64String(base64, buffer , out int bytesParsed);
}
```

Comment: I did not know that was a thing.  I think this should be the new answer,  if using c# 7.2

Comment: Works only in .NET Core 2.1+ or .NET Standard 2.1+

Comment: C# is a compiler and TryFromBase64String is API of .NET framework :)

Comment: This will return false for non-padded strings, here is a fix: `Convert.TryFromBase64String(base64.PadRight(base64.Length / 4 * 4 + (base64.Length % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 4), '='), new Span<byte>(new byte[base64.Length]), out _)`. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, `.FromBase64String` uses this method behind the scenes and simply throws an exception if the underlying call to `.TryFromBase64String` returns `false`. The only difference is that `.FromBase64String` removes trailing whitespace from the input, so you may run into some issues if you were previously relying on it to automatically clean up your input string.

Answer (score 51):

I know you said you didn't want to catch an exception.  But, because catching an exception is more reliable, I will go ahead and post this answer.

```
public static bool IsBase64(this string base64String) {
     // Credit: oybek https://stackoverflow.com/users/794764/oybek
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String) || base64String.Length % 4 != 0
        || base64String.Contains(" ") || base64String.Contains("\t") || base64String.Contains("\r") || base64String.Contains("\n"))
        return false;

     try{
         Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
         return true;
     }
     catch(Exception exception){
     // Handle the exception
     }
     return false;
}
```

**Update:** I've updated the condition thanks to [oybek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955827/487940) to further improve reliability.

Comment: calling `base64String.Contains` multiple times may result in poor performance incase of `base64String` being a large string.

Comment: @NucS You are right, we can use a compiled regex here.

Comment: you can check for `base64String== null || base64String.Length == 0` with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String)`

Comment: Note that a Base64 can contain whitespace (e.g. line breaks) without issue.  They're ignored by the parser.

Comment: I think doing base64String.Contains("\t") etc actually escapes the \t, so it might not be recognized, might have to do base64String.Contains("\\t") but I'm not sure

Comment: Since we have access to the .NET source code now we can see the FromBase64String() function does all these checks. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,08c34f52087ba624 If it's a valid base64 string then you are checking it twice. It maybe chepaer to just try/catch the exception.

Comment: I have plain and base64 encrypted. But when the plain text is 1234, it return true where program will proceed decoded and ends with Exception `Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.`

Answer (score 21):

I believe the regex should be:

```
    Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,2}$")
```

Only matching one or two trailing '=' signs, not three.

`s` should be the string that will be checked. `Regex` is part of the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Comment: does not check if string length is mod of 4 = 0

Answer (score 10):

Just for the sake of completeness I want to provide some implementation.
Generally speaking Regex is an expensive approach, especially if the string is large (which happens when transferring large files). The following approach tries the fastest ways of detection first.

```
public static class HelperExtensions {
    // Characters that are used in base64 strings.
    private static Char[] Base64Chars = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/' };
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to test whether the value is a base64 string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to test</param>
    /// <returns>Boolean value, true if the string is base64, otherwise false</returns>
    public static Boolean IsBase64String(this String value) {

        // The quickest test. If the value is null or is equal to 0 it is not base64
        // Base64 string's length is always divisible by four, i.e. 8, 16, 20 etc. 
        // If it is not you can return false. Quite effective
        // Further, if it meets the above criterias, then test for spaces.
        // If it contains spaces, it is not base64
        if (value == null || value.Length == 0 || value.Length % 4 != 0
            || value.Contains(' ') || value.Contains('\t') || value.Contains('\r') || value.Contains('\n'))
            return false;

        // 98% of all non base64 values are invalidated by this time.
        var index = value.Length - 1;

        // if there is padding step back
        if (value[index] == '=')
            index--;

        // if there are two padding chars step back a second time
        if (value[index] == '=')
            index--;

        // Now traverse over characters
        // You should note that I'm not creating any copy of the existing strings, 
        // assuming that they may be quite large
        for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) 
            // If any of the character is not from the allowed list
            if (!Base64Chars.Contains(value[i]))
                // return false
                return false;

        // If we got here, then the value is a valid base64 string
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406/sam), you can also change the source code slightly. He provides a better performing approach for the last step of tests. The routine

```
    private static Boolean IsInvalid(char value) {
        var intValue = (Int32)value;

        // 1 - 9
        if (intValue >= 48 && intValue <= 57) 
            return false;

        // A - Z
        if (intValue >= 65 && intValue <= 90) 
            return false;

        // a - z
        if (intValue >= 97 && intValue <= 122) 
            return false;

        // + or /
        return intValue != 43 && intValue != 47;
    }
```

can be used to replace `if (!Base64Chars.Contains(value[i]))` line with `if (IsInvalid(value[i]))`

The complete source code with enhancements from [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406/sam) will look like this (removed comments for clarity)

```
public static class HelperExtensions {
    public static Boolean IsBase64String(this String value) {
        if (value == null || value.Length == 0 || value.Length % 4 != 0
            || value.Contains(' ') || value.Contains('\t') || value.Contains('\r') || value.Contains('\n'))
            return false;
        var index = value.Length - 1;
        if (value[index] == '=')
            index--;
        if (value[index] == '=')
            index--;
        for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            if (IsInvalid(value[i]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    // Make it private as there is the name makes no sense for an outside caller
    private static Boolean IsInvalid(char value) {
        var intValue = (Int32)value;
        if (intValue >= 48 && intValue <= 57)
            return false;
        if (intValue >= 65 && intValue <= 90)
            return false;
        if (intValue >= 97 && intValue <= 122)
            return false;
        return intValue != 43 && intValue != 47;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is four `f` (ffff) a valid base64 string? Your code assumes it's a valid one. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes it is. A string `ffff` can be decoded into a valid byte array.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just catch the exception, and return False?

This avoids additional overhead in the common case.

Comment: This is an unusual case I guess where I am going to use the value is  more likely to not be base 64 so I would rather avoid the overhead of the exception.  It is much faster to check before.  I am trying to convert an old system I inherited from clear text passwords to hashed values.

Comment: Regular expressions are never faster than what Tyler is suggesting.

Comment: See the comment at the bottom of my post.  I think depending upon the length of the strings you are working with it can be faster to test first, especially for small strings like hashed passwords.  The string has to be a multiple of 4 to even get to the regex, and then regex on a small string is faster than on a very large string.

Comment: In a perfect world, one should not write code whose business logic is designed or is known to throw exceptions. Exception try/catch block is too expensive to be used as a decision block.

Answer (score 6):

The answer must depend on the usage of the string. There are many strings that may be "valid base64" according to the syntax suggested by several posters, but that may "correctly" decode, without exception, to junk. Example: the 8char string `Portland` is valid Base64. What is the point of stating that this is valid Base64? I guess that at some point you'd want to know that this string should or should not be Base64 decoded.

In my case, I am reading Oracle connection strings from file app.config that may be either in plain text like:

```
Data source=mydb/DBNAME;User Id=Roland;Password=secret1;
```

or in base64 like

```
VXNlciBJZD1sa.....................................==
```

(my predecessor considered base64 as encryption :-)

In order to decide if base64 decoding is needed, in this particular use case, I should simply check if the string starts with "Data" (case insensitive). This is much easier, faster, and **more reliable**, than just try to decode, and see if an exception occurs:

```
if (ConnectionString.Substring(0, 4).ToLower() != "data")
{
  //..DecodeBase64..
}
```

---

I updated this answer; my old conclusion was:

I just have to check for the presence of a semicolon, because that proves that it is NOT base64, which is of course faster than any above method.

Comment: Agree, case specifics also impose certain additional fast checks. Just like plaintext connectionstring vs base64 encoded.

Comment: Fully agree. Any ASCII string of even length will register as base64 according to the approaches mentioned here. "TEST" would register as valid base64, and when automatically compensating for missing padding, so will "TEST1". There really isn't a full-proof way tot test for base64 encoding. This should be the accepted answer, as the other answers are misleading and will lead to many false positives.

Answer (score 5):

Do decode, re encode and compare the result to original string

```
public static Boolean IsBase64(this String str)
{
    if ((str.Length % 4) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //decode - encode and compare
    try
    {
        string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(str));
        string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decoded));
        if (str.Equals(encoded, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Imho this is not really possible.** All posted solutions fails for strings like *"test"* and so on. If they can be divided through 4, are not null or empty, and if they are a valid base64 character, they will pass all tests. That can be many strings ...

So there is no real solution other than **knowing that this is a base 64 encoded string**. What I've come up with is this:

```
if (base64DecodedString.StartsWith("<xml>")
{
    // This was really a base64 encoded string I was expecting. Yippie!
}
else
{
    // This is gibberish.
}
```

I expect that the decoded string begins with a certain structure, so I check for that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the other answers are misleading and will lead to many false positives.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this usage:

```cs
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Check if string is Base64
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="base64"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsBase64String(this string base64)
        {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309379/how-to-check-for-a-valid-base64-encoded-string
            Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[base64.Length]);
            return Convert.TryFromBase64String(base64, buffer, out int _);
        }
    }
```

Then usage

```cs
if(myStr.IsBase64String()){

    ...

}
```

Comment: and thats the best way to do that. People dont remember about extensions, you gave them great lesson.

Answer (score 3):

I will use like this so that I don't need to call the convert method again

```
   public static bool IsBase64(this string base64String,out byte[] bytes)
    {
        bytes = null;
        // Credit: oybek http://stackoverflow.com/users/794764/oybek
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String) || base64String.Length % 4 != 0
           || base64String.Contains(" ") || base64String.Contains("\t") || base64String.Contains("\r") || base64String.Contains("\n"))
            return false;

        try
        {
             bytes=Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Knibb High football rules!

This should be relatively fast and accurate but I admit I didn't put it through a thorough test, just a few.

It avoids expensive exceptions, regex, and also avoids looping through a character set, instead using ascii ranges for validation.

```
public static bool IsBase64String(string s)
    {
        s = s.Trim();
        int mod4 = s.Length % 4;
        if(mod4!=0){
            return false;
        }
        int i=0;
        bool checkPadding = false;
        int paddingCount = 1;//only applies when the first is encountered.
        for(i=0;i<s.Length;i++){
            char c = s[i];
            if (checkPadding)
            {
                if (c != '=')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                paddingCount++;
                if (paddingCount > 3)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if(c>='A' && c<='z' || c>='0' && c<='9'){
                continue;
            }
            switch(c){ 
              case '+':
              case '/':
                 continue;
              case '=': 
                 checkPadding = true;
                 continue;
            }
            return false;
        }
        //if here
        //, length was correct
        //, there were no invalid characters
        //, padding was correct
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsBase64String1(string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
                Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                if (value.EndsWith("="))
                {
                    value = value.Trim();
                    int mod4 = value.Length % 4;
                    if (mod4 != 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why you first try to convert then control other things

Comment: @Snr you are right. I think this is what he need to change :                                 if (value.EndsWith("="))
                {
                    value = value.Trim();
                    int mod4 = value.Length % 4;
                    if (mod4 != 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }

Answer (score 1):

All answers were been digested into 1 function that ensures 100% that its results will be accurate.

**1) Use function as below:**

```cs
string encoded = "WW91ckJhc2U2NHN0cmluZw==";
Console.WriteLine("Is string base64=" + IsBase64(encoded));
```

**2) Below is the function:**

```cs
public bool IsBase64(string base64String)
{
    try
    {
        if (!base64String.Equals(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)))), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) & !System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(base64String, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,2}$"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if ((base64String.Length % 4) != 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String) || base64String.Length % 4 != 0 || base64String.Contains(" ") || base64String.Contains(Constants.vbTab) || base64String.Contains(Constants.vbCr) || base64String.Contains(Constants.vbLf))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pipe I was noob at that time. Pls see now.

Comment: Thats better ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point out that **none of the answers to date are very useable** (depending on your use-case, but bare with me).

All of them will return false positives for strings of a length divisible by 4, not containing whitespace.
If you adjust for missing padding, all strings within the [aA-zZ0-9]+ range will register as base64 encoded.

It doesn't matter if you check for valid characters and length, or use the Exception or TryConvert approach, **all these methods return false positives**.

Some simple examples:

- `"test"` will register as base64 encoded
- `"test1"` will register as base64 encoded if you adjust for missing padding (trailing '=')
- `"test test"` will *never* register as base64 encoded
- `"tést"` will *never* register as base64 encoded

I'm not saying the methods described here are useless, but you should **be aware of the limitations before you use any of these in a production environment**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a regex to do the job.
You'll have to check for something like this: [a-zA-Z0-9+/=]
You'll also have to check the length of the string. I'm not sure on this one, but i'm pretty sure if something gets trimmed (other than the padding "=") it would blow up.

Or better yet check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just make sure each character is within `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `/`, or `+`, and the string ends with `==`.  (At least, that's the most common Base64 implementation.  You might find some implementations that use characters different from `/` or `+` for the last two characters.)

Comment: If I understood, the ending chars depends on the final length of the encoded text. So if the encoded text is not length % 4, then '=' are included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes binary data into ASCII strings using a limited set of characters, you can simply check it with this regular expression:

/^[A-Za-z0-9\=\+\/\s\n]+$/s

which will assure the string only contains A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/', '=', and whitespace.

Comment: That isn't always a sure fire way to tell. Base64 does some padding for you using the `=` character at the end. If that padding is invalid, it's not a correct base64 encoding, even though it matches your regex. You can demo this by finding a base 64 string with 1 or 2 `=` at the end, removing them, and trying to decode it.

Comment: I believe the OP asked to trap for illegal characters, not if the str was legal Base64. If the latter, you are correct, though padding errors in Base64 are easier to trap using exceptions.

Comment: Not true, at least the .Net version of base64 parser ignores padding completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a very similar requirement where I am letting the user do some image manipulation in a `<canvas>` element and then sending the resulting image retrieved with `.toDataURL()` to the backend. I wanted to do some server validation before saving the image and have implemented a `ValidationAttribute` using some of the code from other answers:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class Bae64PngImageAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string))
            return true; // not concerned with whether or not this field is required
        var base64string = (value as string).Trim();

        // we are expecting a URL type string
        if (!base64string.StartsWith("data:image/png;base64,"))
            return false;

        base64string = base64string.Substring("data:image/png;base64,".Length);

        // match length and regular expression
        if (base64string.Length % 4 != 0 || !Regex.IsMatch(base64string, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None))
            return false;

        // finally, try to convert it to a byte array and catch exceptions
        try
        {
            byte[] converted = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am expecting an image/png type string, which is the default returned by `<canvas>` when using `.toDataURL()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check Base64 or normal string

```
public bool IsBase64Encoded(String str)
{

 try

  {
    // If no exception is caught, then it is possibly a base64 encoded string
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
    // The part that checks if the string was properly padded to the
    // correct length was borrowed from d@anish's solution
    return (str.Replace(" ","").Length % 4 == 0);
  }
catch
  {
    // If exception is caught, then it is not a base64 encoded string
   return false;
  }

}
```