# HTTP Request in VBA using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1, Basic Authentication 401 Authentication error

Tags: vba, authentication, http, ms-access

I have an MS Access application that needs to submit HTTP requests to an API that uses basic authentication. I have confirmed that the Base64Encode function below is working as expected, based on an online tool. This is my code currently:

```
Public Function Base64Encode(text As String) As String

  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As Object
  Dim objNode As Object

  Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  Base64Encode = Replace(objNode.text, vbLf, "")

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
  
End Function

Private Sub Cardkey_Lookup_Click()

   Dim req As Object
   Dim username As String
   Dim password As String
   Dim responseCode As Integer

   Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   
   username = "<...>"
   password = "<...>"
   
   Dim encode As String
   encode = Base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
   Debug.Print encode
  
   req.Open "GET", "https://<...>"
   req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
   req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
   req.Send

   responseCode = req.status
   
   Debug.Print responseCode

End Sub
```

The HTTP response is a 401 Authentication error. Do you see any problems with the code, or advice about how to debug?

Comment: Probably not cause of issue, but **&** character is preferred string concatenation operator in Access/VBA.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for recommendation about using & for string concatenation. As you suggested, it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: [How to check for a valid Base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309379/how-to-check-for-a-valid-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for a valid Base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309379/how-to-check-for-a-valid-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: It does not seem that the Base64 encoding is the problem. I used the code from this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba

I also compared the output with this online converter:
https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: What exactly does the whole response look like?  You can edit any sensitive parts.  Are there docs available (which we can view) for the API you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code for basic-authentication using WinHttpRequest in VBA.
Code is based on javascript sample in [Authentication Using Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/authentication-using-script) and tested on the test service of [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/#/Auth/get_basic_auth__user___passwd_) .

```
Sub login()
    Const URL = "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"
    Const Username = "user"
    Const Password = "passwd"
    Const HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0

    Dim Request As New WinHttpRequest

    Request.Open "GET", URL, False
    Request.Send
    Debug.Print "Status=" & Request.status & "(" & Request.statusText & ")" & vbCrLf & _
                "Authenticatication="; Request.getResponseHeader("WWW-Authenticate")

    If Request.status = 401 Then
        Request.SetCredentials "user", "passwd", HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
        Request.Send
        Debug.Print "Status=" & Request.status & "(" & Request.statusText & ")" & vbCrLf & _
                    " Response=" & Request.responseText
    End If

    Set Request = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Status=401(UNAUTHORIZED)
Authenticatication=Basic realm="Fake Realm"

Status=200(OK)
 Response={
  "authenticated": true, 
  "user": "user"
}
```

**UPDATE: Compare WinHttpRequest and XMLHTTP60(request)**

XMLHTTP

```
Sub login_XMLHTTPrequest()
    Const URL = "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"
    Const Username = "user"
    Const Password = "passwd"
    
    Dim Request As New XMLHTTP60

    Request.Open "GET", URL, False
    Request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(Username + ":" + Password)
    Request.Send
    Debug.Print "Status=" & Request.status & "(" & Request.statusText & ")" & vbCrLf & _
                " Response=" & Request.responseText

    Set Request = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Status=200(OK)
 Response={
  "authenticated": true, 
  "user": "user"
}
```

WinHttpRequest

```
Sub login_WinHttpRequest()
    Const URL = "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"
    Const Username = "user"
    Const Password = "passwd"
    
    Dim Request As New WinHttpRequest

    Request.Open "GET", URL, False
    Request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(Username + ":" + Password)
    Request.Send
    Debug.Print "Status=" & Request.status & "(" & Request.statusText & ")" & vbCrLf & _
                " Response=" & Request.responseText

    Set Request = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Status=200(OK)
 Response={
  "authenticated": true, 
  "user": "user"
}
```

To use early-binding add reference to these libraries: `Microsoft XML` and `Microsoft WinHTTP services`:

[image: references]

Comment: I am seeing a 'User-defined type not defined' error for the line: Dim Request As New WinHttpRequest 

Does this require some library? 

What is the difference between SetCredentials and setRequestHeader "Authorization ... "?

Comment: See the updated part of answer about early-binding. You can also continue late-binding using CreateObject.

Comment: I am waiting for administrator access to be granted by my organization. I will update after adding references to the needed libraries.