# RegEx for detecting base64 encoded strings

Tags: php, regex, base64

I need to detect strings with the form **@base64** (e.g. `@VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==`) in my application.

The @ has to be at the beginning and the charset for base64 encoded strings is `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `+`, `/` and `=`. Would be the appropiate regular expresion to detect them?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should do (does not check for proper length!):

```
^@[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={,2}$
```

---

The length of any base64 encoded string must be a multiple of 4, hence the additional.

See here for a solution that checks against proper length: [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data/475217#475217)

A quick explanation of the regex from the linked answer:

```
^@ #match "@" at beginning of string
(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})* #match any number of 4-letter blocks of the base64 char set
(?:
    [A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}== #match 2-letter block of the base64 char set followed by "==", together forming a 4-letter block
| # or
    [A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}= #match 3-letter block of the base64 char set followed by "=", together forming a 4-letter block
)?
$ #match end of string
```

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is that base64 encoded strings have "=" characters only at the end, and have 2 at most. Is possible to check for this?

Comment: ^@(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$ would be correct then?

Comment: Yes and no, if you have confidence on the source with anything that starts with @ symbol then yes that should be good enough. Although I'm assuming you are trying to detect it because it might not be a valid source in which case even something like @HeyThisIsMyTweeterHandle might be detected as base64. Those are things you should consider. If you have control of both ends of the communications I would restructure it a bit. It might also help to simply do a - if first char @ then if base64_decode($str, true) !== false then base64_decode. No reg ex required.

Comment: Well, if you basically just want to check for character set correctness and some basic prefix/suffix checking, then my short one would suffice. The longer one however also checks against proper length.

Comment: That would be nice solution, problem is that I'm trying to extract the base64 from a context (in the middle of a text the user submits, for example). And yes, @HeyThisIsMyTweeterHandle would validate aswell, but that's not a problem for me, as long as it is valid (with proper length aswell) base64

Comment: +1 for J.Romero's suggestion to just use a native php base64 function.

Comment: Good, the only thing is that this also matches nothing at all.

Comment: @AlixAxel: Works fine for me. Mind to share what it doesn't work with?

Comment: @Regexident: What I meant is `preg_match('~^@(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$~', '@'); // 1`, get it?

Answer (score 4):

try with:

```
^@(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

=> [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

Comment: @PierrOz probably extracted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data, but still I'm having a hard time so see what's going on there

Comment: @Federico-Quagliotto how about linking to Gumbo's answer instead of blatantly stealing it without giving credit where credit is due?

Comment: no steal, simply checked on my archive of useful regex. i use base64 for many things, that's all.

i can see that the regex it's pretty the same, sorry for haven't checked on stackoverflow before.

Comment: @PierrOz: see my answer for an explaination of the regex.

Comment: @FedericoQuagliotto: Sorry about the accusation then. Was the first result to show up and looked like a blatant steal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative regular expression:

```
^@(?=(.{4})*$)[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}$
```

It satisfies the following conditions:

- The string length after the @ sign must be a multiple of four - `(?=^(.{4})*$)`
- The content must be alphanumeric characters or + or / - `[A-Za-z0-9+/]*`
- It can have up to two padding (=) characters on the end - `={0,2}`