# How to remove a data uri from text using a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

What's a good way for removing data URIs from a block of text with a **regular expression**? My application has to remove them from email body texts because Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) rejects any email with data URIs.  They should also be removed for security purposes.

Example data URI:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7
```

It could be surrounded by quotes as in HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQA...." />
```

or it could be in a CSS background:

```
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQA....);
```

Comment: You'll probably find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106038/regex-for-detecting-base64-encoded-strings) (as well as the related question linked in a comment) helpful. And of course [preg_replace](http://us2.php.net/preg_replace)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$regex = '~data:[^;]+;[A-Za-z0-9]+,[^")\'\s]+~';
$body = preg_replace($regex, '', $body);
```