# Attacks using data URI scheme and img tags

Tags: image, security, data-uri

Is anyone aware of any security issues with the use of <img src="data:xxxxx"> where the user supplies the content?  Assume the content is validated so it fits the format for a data URI so it can't break out of the tag, and is also restricted to image mime types.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely different code involved, but it's probably not any more attackable than a normal img link.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be secure. As the data URI syntax for images is quite strict:

```
data:image/<subtype>;base64,<base64-stream>
```

it would be easy to validate (see for example [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/475217/53114)).

The only vulnerability I can think of is one within the component that parses/renders the image.