# How to validate Base64 string using regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

How to validate Base64 string in Javascript using regex?

Comment: Why don't you try decoding it? `function validate(str) { try { atob(str); return true; } catch (e) { return false; }}`

Comment: See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77464445/383904)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/475217/1746307) fits you, from another user:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

Comment: This regex will cause a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` with some large base64 strings (like encoded images) so it may be better to use something like https://bit.dev/chriso/validator-js/is-base64/~code to avoid having unexpected errors.