# Validate Base64 Regex causes RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, base64

I have a regex that needs to check whether a base64 is valid. Currently my code in NodeJS looks like this:

```
let base64regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{4})*(([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{2}==)|([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{3}=))?$/;
if (base64regex.test(Payload.fileData) === true) {
 //Further process the filedata
}
```

For smaller base64 files not exceeding 1.6MB, the regex is working fine, but for larger files (>2MB) it is causing:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
```

How do I accept larger base64 data without causing a stack size exceeding error?

I was seeing examples on stackoverflow but none of them have faced this issue. Does the base64regex.test() call happen recursively? And if it does, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of RegExp - which might cause *Maximum call stack size* issues like [this one](https://github.com/miguelmota/is-base64/issues/10)
you might try to use another approach like i.e:

```js
const isValidBase64 = b => {
  try {
    return b.length > 3 && !(b.length % 4) && atob(b) && true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Example:
console.log(
  isValidBase64(""),         // false
  isValidBase64("a"),        // false
  isValidBase64("aZ="),      // false
  isValidBase64("aZ+9===="), // false
  isValidBase64("aZ+9/Š=="), // false
  isValidBase64("aZ+9"),     // true
  isValidBase64("aZ+9/B=="), // true
);
```

(Tested with an image of size >18Mb)

- MDN: [Global fn atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)