# django - url pattern to match url safe base64 string

Tags: python, regex, django

I am using

```
import base64
string_for_url = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(string_to_format)
```

but I'm not sure how to match the generated string in a url pattern.  I found this regex: `(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$` but I don't understand how to convert it into a named group.  As you can tell my regex knowledge is pretty limited.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To name a group, so that it is passed to your view methods prefix it with `(?P<name_of_variable>(group to name))`.  By the way, this is not something specific to django, its part of standard Python [regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

For your example it would be:

```
base64_pattern = r'(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/bar/(?P<base64string>{})'.format(base64_pattern), 'mymethod'),
    # your other patterns
)

# in the view

def mymethod(request, base64string):
   # do stuff with base64string
```

Comment: As a data point, if you need a pattern to match a `uidb64`, according to the [Django 1.6 release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.6/), the following is sufficient:
`r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$'`

This obviously isn't a complete base64 match, but I ended up on this page when I was trying to understand why a pre-1.6 Django password reset example wasn't working.

Answer (score 5):

That regex seems needlessly complicated.

My Django is rusty, but you should be able to do:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'things/(?P<b64_string>.+)', views.b64_view, name='b64_view')
)
```

This would match anything that looked like www.example.com/things/abc123= and pass 'abc123=' into the b64_string argument of the views.b64_string view.

Then you could test for it being b64 encoded simply by trying to decode it.  That would be a lot simpler than trying to find a regex that matched of the b64 encoded string.

Comment: This works as long as you don't have URLs such as 'base64_string/another_token'. For example, you may need to encode an external identifier as base64 (which may contain any character) and then have a confirmation link.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.0, djano uses [captured values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example) in url paths.

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
  path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
]
```

You can, of course, still use regular expressions if the built-in path converters (`str`, `int`, `slug`, `uuid`, `path`) aren't specific enough. In the case of url-safe base 64 encoding, slug may match, but if you need `.`, `=` and `~` then you can define your own:

convertors.py

```
class b64Converter:
    # decide on complexity of your b64 regex by
    # referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/475217
    regex = 'define_your_regex here'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(value)
```

then urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.b64Convertor, 'b64')

urlpatterns = [
    path('widgets/<b64:my_url_param>/', views.widgetview),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Somehow, I keep getting NoReverseMatch errors. Even when I manullay check re.match(pattern, encoded_value) it does match. Very weird.

Answer (score -3):

How about this: `(?P<string_to_format>[0-9A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: base64 encoding outputs more than just alphanumeric chars

Comment: Did you look up base64?