# Cookie encoding Base64

Tags: security, base64, httpcookie

Cookies can be base64 encode. So if I capture pcap, does there any way, I can tell that cookie is base64 encoded? The rationale here is that, one cannot tell seeing the padding (=) sign, that it is base64 encoded, there cannot be any padding. Does cookie format supports the way to tell, if it is encoded, like we have in URI.

Comment: If it looks like a random bunch of alphanumeric characters with occasional `/` and `+` interspersed, it's most likely base64. Period.

Comment: You can even apply that logic in code.

Comment: Yes the issue is how you distinguish between legitimate traffic and encoded traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If characters in the value of the cookie are in the range of the Base64 value set then it **can** be Base64 encoded, you should also check the length, because it must be multiplies of 4.

Comment: That would be performance hit intensive. Isnt there any other way, apart for parsing the string and checking the bounrdy conditions

Comment: It's just one regexp. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/475217/221213