# Decoding/ Encoding how to ignore possible errors and remove/replace wrong chars?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I'm using urllib2 to get the sourcecode of a website which I then filter with regex for a bas64 encoded string, and iterate over it passing the matches to a function:

> ```
> def Base64Decoder(match):  
>     curMatch = match.group().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')  
>     decoded = base64.b64decode(curMatch)   
>     return decoded
> ```

When I print out the returned value of Base64Decoder some chars are wrong, how do I filter them out correctly? I don't want to see gibberish chars like the following:

[image: Cygwin]
[image: linux]

The website's encoding is utf-8 but the returned value of urllib seems to be unicode?

Edit: the sourcecode looks like this (raw)

```
<td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0"))</script></td>
```

and the filtered string is `Base64.decode("MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0` striped to `MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0`

Comment: The Windows console does not by default show UTF-8 encoded characters very well.

Comment: Its not the windows console, its cygwin and on linux it doesn't show either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not stripping it correctly, the `Base64.decode("` prefix is also left in your string after the strip. You can see that in the next example:

```
>>> print base64.b64decode('Base64.decode("MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0')
��^r�^31.13.17.214
```

If you have a pattern similar to this:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('Base64.decode\("(...)"\)')
```

*(See SO question: [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data))*

`group()` will return the fully matched string:

```
>>> pattern.search(s).group()
'Base64.decode("MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0")'
```

The thing you need is:

```
>>> pattern.search(s).groups()[0]
'MzEuMTMuMTcuMjE0'
```

Comment: I am striping it correctly. I'm passing only the base64 encoded string to the function which should return the decoded string.

Comment: @Daapii can you add a `print curMatch` to your function to check?

Comment: Very funny justhalf. @ViktorKerkez I've found the problem I've commented the stripping part out because I've been testing and forgot to remove the hash tag. thanks.

Comment: @Daapii Updated a the answer, added the possible problem solution.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez your regex code could be optimized to just \w instead of \w\d (\w is alphanumeric), thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @Daapii Actually its completely incorrect :D Updated the answer.