# How to RegExp this Base64 encoded 256-bit number without padding

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to regex on the client as well as the server with this validation of a Base64 encoded 256-bit number without the `=` padding.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9+/]{42}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]$
```

This is my code which isn't working as expected as any value seems to return true:

```
$.fn.validateKey = function() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9+/]{42}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]$/
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val());
    return re;
};
```

How can I validate Base 64 encoded 256-bit signing keys without padding with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a `RegExp` object. You want to return its evaluation with an input string instead.

```
$.fn.validateKey = function() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9+/]{42}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]$/;
    return re.test($(this).val());
};
```

[Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) in the comments pointed out something interesting, in which the `/` doesn't need to be escaped in the regex (at least in my browser).

I believe it's due to being part of a character class.

Comment: Thank you so much alex!  What do you mean by that last comment?  I'm using this answer to validate a properly formatted Base64 encoding of a 256-bit number.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21151612/1382306  Is there some other pitfall that I'm missing?  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus I jumped the gun. If it's a subset of encoded data (a number only), you should be right. It's also possible I'm on holidays and forgot a lot of programming.

Comment: I hear you!  Thanks again!

Comment: does the slash inside the character group not need escaping? How so?

Comment: Usually, the delimeter's parse the string which is sent to the regex engine. I would imagine it is seeing this `/^[A-Za-z0-9+/` as the regex, which should throw an error of unmatched `[`. But, this is JS so I am not sure.