# How to check if entered TOTP secret key format is correct?

Tags: javascript, totp

I'm doing a small web project to generate OTP online (like Google authenticator). I'm currently using [otpauth](https://github.com/hectorm/otpauth) library to generate OTP code. It can't generate code if secret key is wrong. So how do I check if entered secret key is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is nothing more than a base32 string, and there are many libraries that can check that.
example: [How to check if a string is base32 encoded in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600848/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-base32-encoded-in-javascript)