# MS SQL XQuery xs:base64Binary returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I (have to) use `base64Binary` to convert my base64 encoded string into bytes. In most cases it works good enough, but from time to time it returns NULL .
For example this works like a charm:

```
DECLARE @Base64String VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Base64String = 'qwerqwerqwerqwer'

declare @Base64Binary VARBINARY(MAX)
set @Base64Binary = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Base64String"))', 'VARBINARY(max)');

select @Base64Binary as 'base64'
```

Result is `0xAB07ABAB07ABAB07ABAB07AB` and that's ok for me.
But if I set `SET @Base64String = 'qwerqwerqwerqwe='` then I get `NULL` as result. Why? I pass pretty valid base64 string and expect not null value. I've tried to find some workaround, but no luck. How can I made `xs:base64Binary` to return valid varbinary value for such input strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having had a little look at this, I would suggest that `qwerqwerqwerqwe=` is not a valid base64 string.

Decoding `qwerqwerqwerqwe=` using a base64 conversion tool in C# renders the following:

```
0xAB07ABAB07ABAB07ABAB07
```

Encoding this in SQL server actually gives the output `qwerqwerqwerqwc=`:

```
DECLARE @Base64String VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Base64Binary VARBINARY(MAX)

SET @Base64Binary = 0xAB07ABAB07ABAB07ABAB07
PRINT @Base64Binary
SET @Base64String = CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Base64Binary"))', 'VARCHAR(max)');
PRINT @Base64String
```

I would suggest that the reason that SQL Server is returning `NULL` to you is that the base64 string you are working with is not actually valid.

Comment: thx for your answer, maybe you have some ideas how to determine validity of base64 string? The most obvious way is regular expression (like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data). But some strings that pass regxeps still return NULL in case of xs:base64Binary conversion. For example qwerqwerqwerq=== or qwerqw== or qwerqwe=

Comment: or maybe you have some ideas how to get validation rules whick uses in xs:base64Binary? it there any way to get sources of it?

Comment: @IgorVSavchenko How are you obtaining these base64 strings?  It may be useful to look at where they are coming from.  The validation of them is fairly straight-forward - if they are `NULL` when converted using the above in SQL Server then they are not valid.

Comment: these are third party values. Yeah, I've stopped at validation using xs:base64Binary. And if it returns null, then I add  '/' symbol(s) to initial data instead of '='. Up to multiple of four length as before. After that all (surprisingly) starts working correctly. This way is ok for me because in my case base64 stores png images and replacing '=' with '/' at the end of string has absolutely no visible impact on resulting image.