# MySQL RegExp incorrectly matches accented characters with utf8 charset and binary collation

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8, base64

I have a table which uses utf8 charset and utf8 binary collation for text fields.
I want all rows in the table which are base64 encoded.
So my query is:

```
select * from test where field REGEXP '^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$' ;
```

But this query matches rows where the field has a binary value like `�ÀJÒŽ©%ù¶±üÊ=`.
The problem with my table is that I am storing binary strings in text fields and I want to base64 encode all such strings.
The regex for base64 encoding match was taken from this question [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)
I think it matches accented characters as well. But I thought regexp worked on byte strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
field REGEXP '...' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

If you have `�` in a field, the 'text' in that field is probably irrecoverable.