# Regular expression is matching entire string

Tags: javascript, regex

https://regex101.com/r/2qRBV7/1

I am trying to get the base64 part of the following (including the `base64:` portion) with this regular expression:

```
.+\[?(.+?)\]?
```

and with this example text:

```
Application key [base64:HlOiabVcCmzUvcnPuCHCOS6nvS89otzCBXKb/PVbI1g=] set successfully.
```

Or this text (this is also an example result):

```
base64:zI1EaQeidtfpLwE9b8sGo5sZDbnzAqULCnL2hT3HoJo=
```

When I run it though, it matches the entire string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to parse or validate Base64 data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)

Comment: @PedroLobito, note that it's indeed a base64, but the structure here is a bit different.

Comment: The op just needs to put `base64` before the regex

Comment: I am also not 100% sure it is always going to be a base64. This is a returned result of another program.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, so, your question doesn't make any sense

Comment: I guess, but for now I will assume that the program always returns a base64, which should be good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
base64:([^\] \b]*)
```

Here is a regex101 example:
https://regex101.com/r/2qRBV7/2

> Catch every char that is not `]`,  and `\b(=word boundry)` after a `base64:`